# MongoDB one collection vs many

Tags: mongodb

I know this question has been asked before, and general consensus seems to be that you should break up documents into multiple collections, probably by document type. However, it is unclear to me why and some things in the docs dont make sense. Namely:

> If the total number of documents is low, you may group documents into
> collection by type

Is the implication here that if total number of documents is quite large, I should lean towards maintaining them in the same collection?

> Distinct collections are very important for high-throughput batch processing

Why? Does it mean that if I only update one document at a time it is not a concern? What about selecting a large number of documents and not updating any?

My problem at hand is that I need to make half a dozen or so types of documents searchable with free text. They need to be searchable by:

1. name and tags with text search
2. producer_id and in some rare cases document_type by exact value

The intuitive solution is to keep all my searchable documents in the same collection because it preserves atomicity of updates to said documents and accords with the "rolling-up" smaller documents as opposed to having a second searchable collection. (or alternatively another DB like ElasticSearch or something) I expect my DB to grow pretty much indefinitely, until irrelevant documents are somehow archived.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

A document in MongoDB is limited to 16 MB in size. This necessitates, eventually, splitting documents into parts.

When an application is communicating with the database, there are generally two considerations that affect performance:

- Application does not want to retrieve unneeded data from the database.
- Application wants to retrieve the required data in the fewest number of requests/round-trips.

So, if you managed to put ALL of your data into a single document, you'd score perfectly on the second requirement but terribly on the first one, and if each field was its own document you'd do well on the first one but terribly on the second one.

Schema design is, to a large extent, an act (and an art) of balancing these requirements.

Regarding your specific situation, without knowing a lot more about what queries your system needs to support, field breakdown, etc. no intelligent answer is possible.

Realistically you should simply go with something that is reasonable. MongoDB's flexible data model means you can change schema in the future, and generally you'd be better off building an application and *getting it working* over getting the schema 100% optimal (which will cease to be 100% optimal as soon as your requirements change, which will be right when you launch).